# ogr2ogr to CSV with quotes breaks with NULL values

Tags: postgis, gdal, csv, ogr2ogr

I have some data stored in a Postgres 13 Postgis 3.1 table that looks like

id(integer),valid_to(timestamp),language(varchar),name(varchar)

1,2021/08/16 11:19:06.493,eng,London

2,2021/08/16 11:19:06.493,cym,Cardiff

3,NULL,,London

As you can see row 3 contains a NULL value for the timestamp and an empty value for the language attributes.

When I use the following GDAL command to export this to CSV the exported data gets corrupted if I use the -lco STRING_QUOTING=ALWAYS.

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV Output.csv PG:"connection string" -lco STRING_QUOTING=ALWAYS -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
```

How can I keep the values (NULL and empty string)?

Comment: Did you try to use `-sql "SELECT id,CASE valid_to IS NULL THEN 'NULL' else valid_to END AS valid_to, language,name FROM mytable"` to be sure NULL becomes a NULL string instead of throwing an error?

Comment: @ThomasG77 - thank you. Yes I could. It means a lot of writing SQL for my ogr commands so was hoping there was a GDAL switch. So I think I will do it in PostGIS and have a simpler export command. Thanks for your help tho

Comment: Maybe someone have clues I do not have, maybe. Let's wait for other answers/comments if any